# Did my teacher correct a word "into" or "as" another word?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I wrote, "*Four flowers is enough*," in an English lesson and my teacher took my worksheet, read it and changed **is** to **are** with his pen. What should I say?

1. My teacher corrected "is" into "are".
2. My teacher corrected "is" as "are".

Comment: "Corrected _is_ **to** _are_."

Comment: My answer are correct. My answer is correct. Which is right? You answer it.

Comment: Sorry but I think you might have misunderstood my question, Lambie.

Comment: No, I didn't. I am trying to get you to answer it by giving you another, simple example, that is the opposite of yours. This is a very basic question.

Comment: I know exactly when to use "is" or "are". I just don't know the suitable preposition going with the verb "correct".

Comment: This question on [english.se] may be helpful [Is it correct to say "correct A to B"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47540/80039)